# Passing different types of SparseArray to a function

Tags: java, android, function, sparse-matrix

HI I have a simple function call:

```
 RemoveSpecific(sheetType); // String sheettype
```

I would like it to call it together with a `SparseArray` as I am going to manipulate a specific `SparseArray` depending on the `sheetType`. Passing that is not a problem however I would like the SparseArray To be Dynamic type??(Not sure if that kind of thing exists) This would save me time writing multiple if statements if I just pass the specific SparseArray to the function.

just be clear:

```
 RemoveSpecific(sheetType, frgag1); //SparseArray<FirstSectionFragment>
 RemoveSpecific(sheetType, frgag2); //SparseArray<SecondSectionFragment>
```

The function itself:

```
if (mPageTitles.size() > 2  && sheetType.equals("somthing")) {
                    mPageTitles.remove(frgag1.get(frgag1.keyAt(frgag1.size() - 1)).getFragContent());
                    frgag1.delete(mInt);
                    if (fso != null && fso.getfr1Details() != null)
                        fso.getfr1Details().getsubfr1Details().delete(mInt);



                mInt--;
                fJobDetails.AnotherFunction("somthing");
                    dialogRmove.dismiss();
            }}
```

Get Frag Contents:

```
(called in different fragments)
public String getFragContent() {
            if (mFragContent == null) {
                Bundle args = getArguments();
                mFragContent = args.getString("content");
            }
            return mFragContent;
        }
```

Comment: You can define the second parameter as Object.

Comment: Show the method declaration for "RemoveSpecific" - my answer depends on what exactly it is you're doing.

Comment: @PPartisan added the function

Comment: Is there a common base class/interface `FirstFragment` and `SecondFragment` extend? I see you have a method call `getFragContent()` that doesn't exist in the stock `Fragment` class

Comment: No they only extend Fragment class, and yes the getFragmentContent() is defined in each fragment individually.

Comment: @PPartisan So I cannot achieve this simply need to create an interface?

Comment: If you want to treat your Fragments in a generic way, then they need to have something in common - if you have a method defined as `getFragmentContent()` in an `interface` called `ContentFragment`, then you can define your method as `RemoveSpecific(String s, SparseArray<? extends ContentFragment> arr)`, for example. Otherwise, you can use reflection and casts, but it isn't very OOP.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void RemoveSpecific(String sheetType, SparseArray<? extends Fragment> DunnoPossible){}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it:

```
public void RemoveSpecific(String sheetType, SparseArray<? extends Fragment> array);
```

However, for a more detailed answer I'd need to see your implementation of `RemoveSpecific`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the function as this:

```
public void RemoveSpecific(String sheetType, SparseArray<?> sparseArray)
{
    //your code
}
```

You can even drop the `String sheetType` and check the `sparseArray` type inside the function, something like this:

```
public void RemoveSpecific(SparseArray<?> sparseArray)
{
    if(sparseArray.size() > 0)
    {
        switch(sparseArray.get(0).getClass().getName())
        {
            case "FirstSectionFragment":
                break;
            case "SecondSectionFragment":
                break;
        }
    }
}
```